# Angular Error: [object Object] resolvePromise

Tags: angular, observable, angular7

I am using Angular 7 and calling simple service using observable

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private http:Http) { }
  registerUser(user):Observable<any>{
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8888/users/register', user, {headers:headers});
  }
}
```

while compiling code is ok but when it hits register url and component then it gives error

```
ERROR Error: "[object Object]"
    resolvePromise http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3159:31
    resolvePromise http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3116:17
    scheduleResolveOrReject http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3218:17
    invokeTask http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2766:17
    onInvokeTask http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:72221:24
    invokeTask http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2765:17
    runTask http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2533:28
    drainMicroTaskQueue http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2940:25
vendor.js:70671:5
defaultErrorLogger
http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:70671:5
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/ErrorHandler.prototype.handleError
http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:70719:9
next
http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:72698:111
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/EventEmitter.prototype.subscribe/schedulerFn<
http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:68245:36
./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js/SafeSubscriber.prototype.__tryOrUnsub
http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:141501:13
./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js/SafeSubscriber.prototype.next
http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:141439:17
./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js/Subscriber.prototype._next
http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:141382:9
./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js/Subscriber.prototype.next
http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:141359:13
./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js/Subject.prototype.next
http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:141124:25
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/EventEmitter.prototype.emit
http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:68229:54
onHandleError/<
http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:72252:57
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke
zone.js:388
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</Zone.prototype.run
zone.js:138
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/NgZone.prototype.runOutsideAngular
http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:72189:16
onHandleError
http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:72252:13
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</ZoneDelegate.prototype.handleError
zone.js:392
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</Zone.prototype.runGuarded
zone.js:154
_loop_1
zone.js:677
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</</api.microtaskDrainDone
zone.js:686
drainMicroTaskQueu
e
zone.js:602
```

if I remove this service class from component `//import {AuthService} from '../../services/auth.service';` then code runs without error.
tried with returning simple `return user` but still error comes.
also tried with returning without observable.
Can you help where I am doing wrong

Comment: Why are you wrapping an observable inside another observable?

Comment: `this.http.post('http://localhost:8888/users/register', user, {headers:headers})` is already `Observable` why are you returning it's with `of`

Comment: i tried with simplest way 
`import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) export class AuthService { user="hi"; constructor() { } registerUser(user){ return this.user; } }`
still same error coming

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The use of `Http` was deprecated since Angular 5. So it won't be available in Angular 7.

**You should be using `HttpClient` and NOT `Http`**. Also, the `Content-Type` header is added by default. So you don't need to add that explicitly.

Finally, `http.post` would already return an Observable. So you don't need to wrap it in an `of`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  registerUser(user): Observable <any> {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8888/users/register', user);
  }

}
```

You'll also have to add `HttpClientModule` to the `imports` array of your `AppModule`:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  ...,
  imports: [..., HttpClientModule, ...]
  ...
})
```

And then in your Component:

```
constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}
...
const user = ...

this.authService.registerUser(user)
  .subscribe(response  => console.log(response));
...
```